# How do I validate a date in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

I want to validate a date in my model in Ruby on Rails, however, the day, month and year values are already converted into an incorrect date by the time they reach my model.

For example, if I enter February 31st 2009 in my view, when I use `Model.new(params[:model])` in my controller, it converts it to "March 3rd 2009", which my model then sees as a valid date, which it is, but it is incorrect.

I would like to be able to do this validation in my model. Is there any way that I can, or am I going about this completely wrong?

I found this "[Date validation](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/53191)" that discusses the problem but it never was resolved.

Comment: This question is currently one of the top Google results for Rails date validation. You might miss it on the first pass like I did: the important part of the selected answer is the validates_timeliness gem. I didn't even read the rest of the answer because I found out about validates_timeliness somewhere else, and that gem does everything I need without me having to write any custom code.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I'm guessing you're using the `date_select` helper to generate the tags for the date. Another way you could do it is to use select form helper for the day, month, year fields. Like this (example I used is the created_at date field):

```
<%= f.select :month, (1..12).to_a, selected: @user.created_at.month %>
<%= f.select :day, (1..31).to_a, selected: @user.created_at.day %>
<%= f.select :year, ((Time.now.year - 20)..Time.now.year).to_a, selected: @user.created_at.year %>
```

And in the model, you validate the date:

```
attr_accessor :month, :day, :year
validate :validate_created_at

private

def convert_created_at
  begin
    self.created_at = Date.civil(self.year.to_i, self.month.to_i, self.day.to_i)
  rescue ArgumentError
    false
  end
end

def validate_created_at
  errors.add("Created at date", "is invalid.") unless convert_created_at
end
```

If you're looking for a plugin solution, I'd checkout the [validates_timeliness](http://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/) plugin. It works like this (from the github page):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_date :date_of_birth, on_or_before: lambda { Date.current }
  # or
  validates :date_of_birth, timeliness: { on_or_before: lambda { Date.current }, type: :date }
end
```

The list of validation methods available are as follows:

```
validates_date     - validate value as date
validates_time     - validate value as time only i.e. '12:20pm'
validates_datetime - validate value as a full date and time
validates          - use the :timeliness key and set the type in the hash.
```

Comment: The suggested solution does not work for me and I am using Rails 2.3.5

Comment: I rewrote it to be cleaner, and tested it against Rails 2.3.5 and this does work for me.

Comment: Hi Jack, I've tried your solution, it works for me adding attr_accessible :day, :month, :year. Which doesn't make sense for me... Thanks if you have any idea!

Comment: In Rails 3, I'm using https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/ and it's awesome.

Comment: The [validates_timeliness](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness/) plugin/gem is really nice to use. Works a charm and keeps my code smaller. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 20):

Using the chronic gem:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :valid_date?

  def valid_date?
    unless Chronic.parse(from_date)
      errors.add(:from_date, "is missing or invalid")
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: In this specific example, I had to use `Chronic.parse(from_date_before_type_cast)` in order to get the string value input. Otherwise Rails would typecast the string with `to_date` since the field was a `datetime` field.

Answer (score 18):

If you want Rails 3 or Ruby 1.9 compatibility try the [date_validator](http://rubygems.org/gems/date_validator) gem.

Comment: I just tried this. Took all of 2 minutes to install and add validation!

Answer (score 12):

Active Record gives you `_before_type_cast` attributes which contain the raw attribute data before typecasting.  This can be useful for returning error messages with pre-typecast values or just doing validations that aren't possible after typecast.

I would shy away from Daniel Von Fange's suggestion of overriding the accessor, because doing validation in an accessor changes the accessor contract slightly. Active Record has a feature explicitly for this situation.  Use it.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late here, but thanks to "[How do I validate a date in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails/4941755#4941755)" I managed to write this validator, hope is useful to somebody:

Inside your `model.rb`

```
validate :date_field_must_be_a_date_or_blank

# If your field is called :date_field, use :date_field_before_type_cast
def date_field_must_be_a_date_or_blank
  date_field_before_type_cast.to_date
rescue ArgumentError
  errors.add(:birthday, :invalid)
end
```

Comment: Better late than never, and in time for me!

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to handle the date string before it is converted to a date in your model, I'd override the accessor for that field

Let's say your date field is `published_date`. Add this to your model object:

```
def published_date=(value)
    # do sanity checking here
    # then hand it back to rails to convert and store
    self.write_attribute(:published_date, value) 
end
```

Comment: I don't know if I'll use this for this purpose, but it's a great suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non-chronic answer..

```
class Pimping < ActiveRecord::Base

validate :valid_date?

def valid_date?
  if scheduled_on.present?
    unless scheduled_on.is_a?(Time)
      errors.add(:scheduled_on, "Is an invalid date.")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This always returns false: `"1/1/2013".is_a?(Date)` - The date comes from user input, so it's being fed as a string. I'd have to parse it as a date first?

Comment: Correct. `Date.parse("1/1/2013").is_a?(Date)`, but you could see that if it doesn't parse at all, its also probably not a date.

Comment: Need to rescue argument error... ahh, it would have been awesome if it just parsed the string automatically... oh well, there are gem's for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate the date and time like so (in a method somewhere in your controller with access to your params if you are using custom selects) ...

```
# Set parameters
year = params[:date][:year].to_i
month = params[:date][:month].to_i
mday = params[:date][:mday].to_i
hour = params[:date][:hour].to_i
minute = params[:date][:minute].to_i

# Validate date, time and hour
valid_date    = Date.valid_date? year, month, mday
valid_hour    = (0..23).to_a.include? hour
valid_minute  = (0..59).to_a.include? minute
valid_time    = valid_hour && valid_minute

# Check if parameters are valid and generate appropriate date
if valid_date && valid_time
  second = 0
  offset = '0'
  DateTime.civil(year, month, mday, hour, minute, second, offset)
else
  # Some fallback if you want like ...
  DateTime.current.utc
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this method instead

```rb
  validate :birthday_must_be_a_date

  def birthday_must_be_a_date
    birthday&.to_date || errors.add(:birthday, :blank)
  rescue Date::Error
    errors.add(:birthday, :invalid)
  end
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried the [`validates_date_time`](https://github.com/nickstenning/validates_date_time) plug-in?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I like my answer better. Two people agree.

Comment: @Pinal The link is indeed dead now.