# Rails date check if parsable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, date, parsing

I have a datetime picker which sends the checkin & checkout dates with search box. Then the url looks like;

```
http://localhost:3000/locations/listings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=london&start_date=12%2F04%2F16&end_date=20%2F04%2F16
```

and I take the params hash and parse the string,

```
start_date = Date.parse(params[:start_date])
end_date = Date.parse(params[:end_date])
```

first of all, I have to check  `if (start_date.present? && end_date.present?)` and that works fine.

But if the user manually types something else rather than the date to url such as;

```
http://localhost:3000/locations/listings?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=london&start_date=londoneye6&end_date=20%2F04%2F16
```

Then of course I get an error;

```
invalid date
```

How should I control if the string is parsable on controller action. I should be also checking `london-eye, london/eye` strings, which include `- /`

Thank you

Comment: validate time with Date.parse, and just trap `ArgumentError` exception on parse returning `nil` out

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ thank you. Can you be more specific how to do it?

Comment: please see my answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is a valid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955830/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to try parsing the string and rescue `ArgumentError`

```
begin
   myDate = Date.parse("31-01-2016")
rescue ArgumentError
   # handle invalid date
end
```

one line (please note that this rescues *all* errors)

```
myDate = Date.parse("31-01-2016") rescue nil
```

Comment: `Date.parse("11_d")` is `2021-02-11`

Answer (score 5):

You can validate time with `Date.parse`, and just trap `ArgumentError` exception on parse returning `nil` out:

**controller**:

```
def param_date date
   Date.parse(date)
rescue ArgumentError
   nil
end

start_date = param_date(params[:start_date])
end_date = param_date(params[:end_date])
```