# Parse date in format 'dd-m-yy' to a valid date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to parse a date from excel file, it's in format `14-3-17` because excel changes it to that...

What is the best way to parse it to a valid date?

```
'14-03-17'.to_date #=> Sat, 17 Mar 0014
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955830/checking-to-see-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Date.strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/strptime/class) to parse as well as format the parsed date,
take a look [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime) to find the list of formatting options available.

Here's an example:

```
Date.strptime("14-03-17", "%d-%m-%y")
=> Tue, 14 Mar 2017
```

Goodluck.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Date.`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse):

```
Date.parse('14-3-17'.split('-').reverse.join('-'))
#=> Tue, 14 Mar 2017
```