# Ruby Regular Expression to validate day and month of a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

On [rubular](http://rubular.com) I tested and confirmed that this does a good job confirming the desired *format* of a date entry:

```
\A\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\z
```

Tests:

```
01/02/2000 #pass
11/21/2014 #pass
11-21-2014 #fail
A3-21-2014 #fail
```

I want to make it a little bit better, and it will be good enough for me.  What I want is to confirm that the "month field" (the first two digits) is anywhere from 01 - 12, where each single digit is led by a zero.  (Ex: 01,02,03 etc as opposed to: 1,2,3).

Next: I want to do the same thing for the next two digits to confirm that the next two digits (the day field) is between 01 - 31.  Same thing: Each single digit needs to lead with a zero.

Tests:

```
01/02/2017 #pass
12/31/2017 #pass
1/02/2017  #fail
01/2/2017  #fail
50/01/2017 #fail
01/50/2017 #fail
```

I realize that this regex will be inaccurate for those months that have fewer than 31 days, but it is good enough for what I am doing.

Comment: It seems like it would be less work _and_ more accurate to just use `Date.parse()` on the input string and catch the exception thrown by invalid dates.  You could then do a string comparison against the formatted output from the parsed `Date` object to make sure it matched your input format.

Comment: `Date.parse` will fail if the date isn't in `%d/%m/%y` format for certain days of each month if presented with U.S. formatted dates in `%m/%d/%y` format. (The OP's regex doesn't check for that). `parse` is also slower than using explicit DateTime/Time format strings.

Comment: Don't try to do it with a regex. While it's possible, it'll result in a complicated pattern that could easily be replaced with a bit of smart code. We'd like to see your attempt to solve this as currently it looks like you want us to write a solution for you.

Comment: So how then do I validate a date in an american date format, "mm/dd/yyyy", without regex?  This is what I have:   `validates_format_of :date_of_birth, :with => /\A\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d\z/, allow_blank: true, message: "Date of Birth Format Invalid: mm/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: If you know your dates are _ALWAYS_ in U.S. format, then simply use `strptime` to parse it using a `%m/%d/%Y` format string. It'll raise an exception if the value doesn't fit. A regular expression is good for looking at the structure, but they're not good for seeing if values fit within a range. It _CAN_ be done but there are easier ways of seeing if the values are valid.

Comment: Just to clarify: `Date.parse` doesn't know the different between dates in `%m/%d/%y` format and those in `%d/%m/%y` format, nor can it determine which to use, so, because `%d/%m/%y` is more prevalent it uses that. Passing in U.S. dates can result in Date trying to create months > 12, and it'll complain. `Date.parse('1/31/2001') # ~> ArgumentError: invalid date`

Comment: Why the down vote? Isn't this question useful and shows an honest attempt?

Comment: Why is this even a validation? Shouldn't `date_of_birth` have a `date` type in the database? Then the model can require incoming dates to be in ISO8601 format and the controller can clean things up if you want to allow other formats.

Comment: Hover over the up and down vote buttons to see what they mean, unfortunately they get used for disproval or approval for a variety of other reasons too. Dealing with dates is not a trivial problem and any time a user can enter the date the odds are really good they'll get it wrong. A date picker is essential in a GUI. If you're getting data as a file then you have to check to see if the sender is using the right format; It can be very difficult when dealing with multiple sources of the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was used the [american_date](https://rubygems.org/gems/american_date) gem.  On your date inputs: the user should enter the date in the format of: "mm/dd/yyyy".

In order to force the user to enter the date in this format: I used [jquery-inputmask-rails](https://rubygems.org/gems/jquery-inputmask-rails).  I defined my mask like so:

```
$('.mask_american_date').inputmask({mask: "99/99/9999"});
```

Now there will be a nice mask on the date input that looks like this:

```
__/__/____
```

Now: all you need is a presence validator for the date field in your model:

```
validates_presence_of :date_of_birth, message: "Date is either invalid or is not present".
```

And this covers everything.  How american date works is it takes the user input and attempts to convert it into a date.  If it cannot convert the user input into a date for any reason: it will return `nil` which triggers the above validation.

- This includes a bad month entry or a bad day entry.  American Date is smart enough to know, for example, that September only has 30 days in it. So: if the user enters "31" for the day section, ex: 09/31/2017, american date will convert the date to `nil`.

Comment: This won't fix the problem if someone from a different part of the world enters a date in DD/MM/YYYY format, it'll just tell them it's invalid and will frustrate them. You should ask them their locale and adjust based on that, or use a date picker which will not allow them to enter invalid information.

Comment: @theTinMan it was good enough for me. I am aware that the american_date gem only works for america.  I'm only dealing with the US so it is good enough. Perhaps you could provide a solution then?

Comment: There is no solution unless you know, beyond all doubt, that the dates are from the U.S. If you know that, then it's a trivial problem, solved simply by using `strptime('some_mm/dd/yyyy', '%m/%d/%Y')`. No gem is needed because Date knows how many days are in each month.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5355056/128421 goes further into the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well this should get you most of the way there:

```
/((02\/[0-2]\d)|((01|[0][3-9]|[1][0-2])\/(31|30|[0-2]\d)))\/[12]\d{3}/
```

Granted it does not handle the following:

- Leap Years e.g. 02/29 is acceptable regardless of the year
- All Years from 1000-2999 are acceptable
- Months with only 30 days e.g. 09/31 is acceptable

Small Breakdown in case links break:

Here is the runout on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/sKuXCDKanN)
Here is an explanation from [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bwuQuB/2)

- `(02\/[0-2]\d)` - Starts with 02/ then allow 0-2 followed by 0-9
- OR `((01|[0][3-9]|[1][0-2]\/(31|30|[0-2]\d))` - Starts with (01 or 0 followed by 3-9 or 1 followed by 0-2) followed a / followed by 31 or 30 or 0-2 followed by 0-9
- In both cases must be followed by 1 or 2 followed by 3 digits 0-9

Really wish ruby supported look behind conditionals like true pcre [Example for edification](https://regex101.com/r/bwuQuB/1)

**As a Note**: as mentioned in the comments rescuing a parsing failure is probably easier than using a regex but I figured since you asked.

Comment: [Close only counts in horseshoes and grenades.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Close+only+counts+in+horseshoes).

Comment: @caryswoveland technically I succeeded *"I want to make it a little bit better, and it will be good enough for me."* Although I'd call it more a horseshoe than a hand grenade. Close also counts in bocce and I'd take close in the lottery as well ;)