# Can't compare date with a string converted into a date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I'm using the [Rspotify gem](https://github.com/guilhermesad/rspotify) and trying to compare the date I get back for a given album (i.e. `album.release_date`) with the current user's last sign in date (i.e. `current_user.last_sign_in_at`). The `release_date` is a string.

Example album release date: `"2017-03-18"`

Example last sign in date: `Sat, 13 May 2017 18:57:28 UTC +00:00`

I've looked at and tried every solution I could find online, including:

- Various string to date methods (e.g. `DateTime()`, `.to_time`, etc.)
- Converting the string to a date and then both dates to integers
- Adding a time zone

But I keep running into a couple errors.

The two most common errors I get are `argument out of range` and `invalid date`. I'm further confused because, in the console when using byebug, I'm able to compare the two dates with a few different conversion methods.

Comment: Ref :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955830/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hadn't accounted for strings without months or days (e.g. '2010' or '2010-10').

Answer (score 1):

You just need to convert both the formats to date

```
"2017-03-18".to_date > "Sat, 13 May 2017 18:57:28 UTC +00:00".to_date
#=> false
```

And you can compare the dates

Same with time

```
"2017-03-18".to_time > "Sat, 13 May 2017 18:57:28 UTC +00:00".to_time
#=> false
```

Comment: If I use `to_date`, I get an `invalid date` error. If I use `to_time`, I get an `argument out of range` error. It looks like it's only happening when converting the `album.release_date`, though -- the `last_sign_in_at` is fine.

Comment: When I use `to_time`, this is the format for the `release_date`: `2017-03-18 00:00:00 +0000`, and this is the format for the `last_sign_in_at`: `2017-05-13 18:57:28 +0000`. And when I use `to_date`, this is the format for the `release_date`: `Sat, 18 Mar 2017`, and this is the format for `last_sign_in_at`: `Sat, 13 May 2017`. How else should I make sure the date format is proper?

Answer (score -1):

Try and see **.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')**. It returns only the year, month and date and now the dates can be compared.