# Bug in `Date#strtime`? It parses days which more than 30/31 in a month, confusing them with the years

Tags: ruby, date

Why the string of date with specific format is successfully parsed by `strptime` method with an explicit different format?

need to explicitly accepted format date for API

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Date.strptime('01-01-1970', '%Y-%m-%d')
=> #<Date: 0001-01-19 ((1721442j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
irb(main):003:0> Date.strptime('01-01-1970', '%Y-%m-%d').to_s
=> "0001-01-19"
irb(main):004:0> Date.strptime('01-01-1970', '%Y-%m-%d').year
=> 1
irb(main):005:0> Date.strptime('01-01-1970', '%Y-%m-%d').day
=> 19
```

Expect: test passed

```
it 'raises an exception when wrong format' do
 expect { Date.strptime('01-01-1970', '%Y-%m-%d') }.to raise_exception(ArgumentError, 'invalid format')
end
```

Actual: `expected ArgumentError with "invalid format" but nothing was raised`

Comment: Because of how Ruby parses dates it's perfectly valid, which you can show yourself by running it in the repl.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is a valid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955830/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-date)

Comment: @DaveNewton did you see the format? `'%Y-%m-%d'` what is `perfectly valid`, the `1970` of days?

Comment: @maxpleaner did you even read? the question is: `why it's happened?`, not: `how to parse string date?`

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak I did indeed. And yes, because of how it parses dates, as explained in detail by Sergio, it will parse to a valid date. You'll need to use a regex or a stricter date parsing mechanism.

Comment: yup, I expect something like this: `[/\d{4}(-\d{2}){2}/]`, anyway thanks

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak: oh wow, it never occurred to me that one could use a quantifier here (for the `-\d{2}` part). While your version does the same thing, maybe a `/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/` will express the intent more clearly.

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak I'm just trying to help. You expected strftime to raise an error with these inputs but it doesnt. Why not? Feel free to look at the source code of it. But as that linked answer says, there are other ways to go about accomplishingg your _goal_ (which is to raise an error on parsing invalid date)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two hidden questions, I think.

> Why is `01` a valid match for `%Y` (which means "year including century")

Because why assume 4 digit years? Otherwise you wouldn't be able to specify 3-digit years (for example, year 882 was when Kiev became capital of Rus). Or maybe in this case you *did* mean year 1. Ruby has no idea.

> Why is `1970` a match for `%d`?

Because that's how [`strptime(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) works (which it's supposed to be compatible with). Once format descriptor `%d` ("day, 1-31") is satisfied with `19`, the string stops being processed.

> The return value of the function is a pointer to the first character not processed in this function call. In case the input string contains more characters than required by the format string the return value points right after the last consumed input character.

Comment: hm... why the `Ruby` is splitting the string and analyze it by parts?
I mean, if I provide the explicit format, then I expect the parsing in this logic scope of format, I have not idea why it should work not in complex of format

Comment: @AlexeyStrizhak: maybe you simply have wrong expectations about what format specifiers do or how strict they are. If you _must_ reject the date strings from your question (as not conforming to your format), check the string with a regex before parsing it as date. This is actually a problem you can see in coding interviews (I did).

Comment: make sense. thank you

|> wrong expectations|

yeah, looks so. honestly, I'll re-read your answer with try to understand, thank you!

Comment: I was unaware of this behaviour (re day), and am wondering why the Ruby monks chose to do it that way. After all, if we are to permit `Date.strptime('28-03-2019', '%Y-%m-%d')` why assume the day is  `"20"` by the string `"19"` and not the day `"2"` followed by the string `"019"`? Moreover, if this were an inadvertent reversing of the format string, by not raising an exception Ruby is making it harder for the coder to track down the bug. Can you or anyone suggest a reason for this language design decision?

Comment: @CarySwoveland: I'm betting on compatibility with C stdlib. I mean, if we're copying `printf` and its format string behaviour, why deviate in implementation of this one? Principle of least surprise and all.

Comment: @CarySwoveland "why assume the day is "20" by the string "19" and not the day "2" followed by the string "019"" - well, day _is_ defined as having values from 1 to 31. So you _have_ to look at two digits. But a day will never have three digits. Unlike a year.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: some more examples of parsing strings as days: `2o10` => 2 (2 is not followed by a digit); `3110` => 31, but `3210` => ArgumentError (day can't be 32. We also can't fallback to splitting this into 3 + 210, because we have no basis to assume that it'd be the correct recovery. Data is ambiguous. Panic and let the user deal with it). It all sounds very logical to me.

Comment: It's going to be tough, but I guess I'll have to live with it.