# Date validation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have an Active Record model that contains two attributes: start_date and end_date. How do I go about validating the following:

1. The dates are in the correct (yyyy-mm-dd) format
2. That end_date > start_date

Answer (score 21):

Does it matter what format they are stored in?  A Date object is a Date object.  Are you storing it in a date column in the DB?

Here is how I do the validation:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :validate_end_date_before_start_date

  def validate_end_date_before_start_date
    if end_date && start_date
      errors.add(:end_date, "Put error text here") if end_date < start_date
    end
  end
end
```

Keep in mind this does not check for nil dates... you might want to if either could be.

FYI, if you want to be able to accept a variety of formats Chronic is pretty flexible.

Comment: Well, I'm populating my "MyModel" object in the controller action with the following line of code:

mymodel = MyModel.new(params[:mymodel])

I'm guessing that is setting the start_date and end_date as strings. I suppose I could manually convert the params[:start_date] and params[:end_date] to date objects first before storing them in my model. Is that what you would recommend? (and yes, I'm storing them in date columns in the db)

Comment: you can pass the dates as strings the params hash without any problems... they will be converted into Date objects automatically.  But a little word of warning: if you pass in a string like 01-04-1990, it will not be interpreted as Jan 4, 1990 but as April 1, 1990.  However, YYYY-MM-DD is unambiguous and will be parsed correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I ran into that mm/dd/yyyy vs dd/mm/yyyy issue. I decided to simply ask for user input in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Comment: @kevin One of the reasons I am using the chronic gem is to (among other things) parse mm/dd/yyyy.  I overrode my end_date setter using chronic.

Comment: There is a problem with the answer above. The "s" behind validates leads to a crash. Took me 30 minutes to figure that out. Correct form:'validate :validate_end_date_before_start_date   '

Comment: @Michael Schmitz - good catch.  I corrected the answer.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do date validation:

[How do I validate a date in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails/597776#597776)

And seeing if a date is greater than another date, you can just use the greater than/less than operators on date objects:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :006 > d1 = Date.civil(2011, 05, 01)
 => #<Date: 2011-05-01 (4911365/2,0,2299161)> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :007 > d2 = Date.civil(2011, 01, 01)
 => #<Date: 2011-01-01 (4911125/2,0,2299161)> 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :008 > d2 > d1
 => false 
ruby-1.9.2-p136 :009 > d2 < d1
 => true
```

So in your example:

```
def validate_dates
  errors.add("Created at date", "is invalid.") unless convert_created_at
  errors.add("End Date" , "is invalid") if end_date > start_date
end
```