# Validating DateTime format in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm adding validations to a model with a **start** column that is typed as **datetime**

Currently I only use the **date_select** form helper, but have left the column typed to datetime in case I decide I want to use the time value in the future.

I am currently using:

```
validates :start, :presence => true
```

But I want to know if there is a :format => that will ensure I'm getting a date passed in. I know it's unlikely that someone would change the select boxes around, but I figure you can't be too careful, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends what date formats you want to accept.

f.e.

```
validates :start, :presence => true, :format => /(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d/
```

for dd-mm-yyyy as dateformat.

Google for date regexp!

Since my answer was downvoted i give it another try:

```
   validate do
      self.errors[:start] << "must be a valid date" unless (DateTime.parse(self.start) rescue false)
   end
```

Comment: Thank you! Currently I'm using the date_select form helper within rails. So I wasn't exactly sure how that passed the variables to the model. Is it all sent as one format like 12/10/2011? If it is, this regex should be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: No, sorry, I think this solution works only if you have a single textfield.

Comment: Maybe I'll do a single text field - will be easier to hook up a javascript selector anyway. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Yeah you are right.. jQuery Datepicker is a good choice for example!

Comment: Going ahead and accepting because I don't think there is any other way to validate the date_select form. Thanks! Looking into getting JQuery UI up and running!

Comment: Remembering that this regex does not check if the date is valid, it accepts 02/31/2012 for example but the database not.

Comment: This another post can help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails

Comment: the parentheses is required: validate do
      self.errors[:start] << "must be a valid date" unless (DateTime.parse(self.start) rescue false)
   end

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [validates_timeliness gem](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness).

This gem enables some useful date and time-relations validations. In your case, you might use it to validate your `start` attribute like this:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_datetime :start
  # or
  validates :start, presence: true, timeliness: {type: :datetime}
end
```

Comment: @kleopatra thanks for the advice. I extended the answer to refer to the particular context of the question and making it stand-alone. Cheers!