# How to validate (and handle) if value passed to .to_date is valid or returns error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, date, ruby-on-rails-4, error-handling

If user inserts a value that is not accepted to the [`to_date`](http://apidock.com/rails/String/to_date) method, e.g. "some gibberish", it returns:

"ArgumentError: invalid date"

How could I construct a custom validation that returns an validation message to user and doesn't halts the application?

I was thinking that reusing the code from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8608559/3205492) would be a good idea, but I don't know how to apply it to `to_date`.

```
validate do
  self.errors[:start] << "must be a valid date" unless DateTime.parse(self.start) rescue false  
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be achieved with rescue, and then addes to `errors`

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

  validate do |post|
    begin
      Date.parse(post.date)
    rescue ArgumentError
      errors.add(:date, "must be a valid date")
    end
  end

## Another way

  validate do |post|
    # make sure that `date` field in your database is type of `date`
    errors.add(:date, "must be a valid date") unless post.date.try(to_date) 
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a custom validation method out of your code, but I don't get nowhere.. :/

Comment: I'm appearantly doing something wrong. With the second solution I'm receiving "NameError: undefined local variable or method" and with the first: "TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String". But it looks correct what you have suggested so I will just try to research my code a bit more.

Comment: Seriously, if you pass by Stockholm any day, I owe you a dinner! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Numbers heh ;) too cold for me, anyway thanks for the cool offer. :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing your own validation (and having to write tests for it!) I suggest the [validates_timeliness gem](https://github.com/adzap/validates_timeliness)

Using it is as simple as

```
  validates_date :attribute_name
```