# RAILS: date_select validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, date

**custom_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.date_select :creation_date %>
```

I have a column `creation_date` in my database with `date` type. Everything works fine, but I need to validate `:creation_date` in my **server.rb** model.
I need to validate:

1. Date type to be valid
2. Max\min date start\end period

Simple `:creation_date` validation `validates_date :creation_date, presence =>true ...` calling `Undefined Method` error. 
I read on a forum that if date is not valid, then my `:creation_date` will be set to `nil`. 
I guess we can check `:creation_date` for `nil` value to deal with 1 item in the list? 
And how can I implement second item?

**UPD (Resolved):**

Problem was in neasted model. I tried to validate attribute of my **user** model in **server.rb**. I moved validation to **user.rb** and now i'm able to validate `:creation_date` with [timeliness gem](https://github.com/adzap/timeliness)

Comment: Use `presence: true`..

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597328/how-do-i-validate-a-date-in-rails

Comment: Because if it is not valid, then it will be set to nil and presence will be false? Am i right? And what about second item in my list?

Comment: Yeah, i saw that, but i need to validate date_select and not creating fields for year, month and day separately, if it is possible.

Comment: To check validity, how about `Date.parse` protected with a rescue?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :mydate_is_date

  private

  def mydate_is_date
    unless :mydate.is_a?(Date)
      errors.add(:mydate, 'must be a valid date') 
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> validates :creation_date, presence: true

This method is from default rails validation which checks for blank values or invalid dates if it is a date field.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your first item, you've been given a number of totally acceptable answers (I would implement G.B.'s, personally).

Regarding your second item, it depends a little bit upon what your bounds are. In my opinion, the easiest way is to simply compare date objects. For instance:

```
validate :mydate_is_within_range

private

def mydate_is_within_range
  unless mydate > min_date && mydate < max_date
    errors.add(:mydate, 'date must be within the allowed range')
  end
end
```

Now, this relies on having the minimum and maximum dates in date form, but I *suspect* you already have this? Regardless, it should set you on the right track.